# Loading current revision node

Tags: database, nodes

How do I construct an entity condition so that it loads current revision of all nodes? This is my attempt.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'xxxxx')  
->fieldCondition('xxx_module','tid', $tid,'=')  
->age(FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT)
->execute();
```

Instead of loading the current revision, it loads the published revision.

Comment: By current revision of a node you mean the latest?

Comment: I mean the draft one.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `EntityFieldQuery` checks the currently logged-in user has the permission to access the queried entities. This is could be undesired, especially when the queried entity is not shown to the users, for example when a module just needs to get a list of entities to delete them.

To avoid `EntityFieldQuery` checks the currently logged-in user has the permission to access the entity, you need to use the following method:

- `addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')` for Drupal 7.15 or higher version
- `addMetaData('account', user_load(1))` for previous versions

Assuming you are using any version higher than 7.15, you code should be the following one.

```
query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'xxxxx')  
  ->fieldCondition('xxx_module','tid', $tid,'=')  
  ->age(FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT)
  ->addTag('DANGEROUS_ACCESS_CHECK_OPT_OUT')
->execute();
```

There could be a module that alter the query done from `EntityFieldQuery` and doesn't respect that tag; in that case, the query could still not return an entity revision that is not published.